# Start using Redis with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis

How do I start using [Redis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis_%28data_store%29) database with ASP.NET?

What I should install and what I should download?

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 with C#.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can access a Redis instance from C# using the servicestack driver. You can download the code from [its GitHub repository](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis).

Comment: It's worth noting that the ServiceStack driver has a limit of 6,000 requests per day unless you pay $$$.

Comment: Where can I read about these limitations and payment options?

Comment: @SerhiyPrysyazhnyy https://servicestack.net/download#free-quotas and https://servicestack.net/pricing

Answer (score 30):

FYI, both the:

- [RedisStackOverflow](http://www.servicestack.net/RedisStackOverflow/) with [C# Source Code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RedisStackOverflow/RedisStackOverflow.ServiceInterface/IRepository.cs) and
- [RedisAdminUI](http://www.servicestack.net/RedisAdminUI/AjaxClient/) with [C# Source Code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.RedisWebServices/)

are open source ASP.NET web applications that only use the ServiceStack.Redis C# client.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RedisStackOverflow/RedisStackOverflow/Global.asax.cs) of how you would use an [Inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) (IoC) container to register a Redis client connection pool and its accompanying `IRepository` with an IoC:

```
//Register any dependencies you want injected into your services
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager());
container.Register<IRepository>(c => new Repository(c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>()));
```

Note: if you're just starting out with the client, I recommend you go through the *[C# Client Wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki)*, Especially the [Designing a Simple Blog application with Redis tutorial](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/DesigningNoSqlDatabase)*.

Comment: Would it be recommended that IRedisClientsManager be registered in singleton scope if the IoC container supports it (i.e. ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Container) in Funq or InSingletonScope() with Ninject)?

Comment: Yes it maintains the connection pool on the instance. To be useful the client connections should be managed from the same pool. Note: Funq is singleton by default, no need to be explicit.

Comment: Ah, the bit about Funq being singleton by default is what I missed. This explains why it's not explicit in any example I've seen. (I'm used to Ninject where transient scope is the default.) Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 5):

Recommend You [**StackExchage.Redis**](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis) Client Library for ASP.net. Recommended By Microsoft as you see in this [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690521.aspx) article. it is free and opensource.
Also Look at complete List of Redis Clients available: http://redis.io/clients

And for Installing The Redis and using Client in Windows Based Platforms Download And Install [**Redis Service (Server and Client Tools With Documentaion)**](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis) Wrote By Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [Integrating Redis in your Asp.Net MVC Project](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/integrating-redis-in-your-asp-net-mvc-project):
The first thing to do is to install Redis on your machine. It is created for Linux but has a simple installation for Windows. In fact, Microsoft has a open source implementation where you can download the installation from this [GitHub](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases) page.

Install StackExchange.Redis from Nuget.
Then you can use it like this:

```
public class RedisCache : ICache
{
private readonly ConnectionMultiplexer redisConnections;

public RedisCache()
{
    this.redisConnections = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
}
public void Set<T>(string key, T objectToCache) where T : class
{
    var db = this.redisConnections.GetDatabase();
    db.StringSet(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectToCache
                , Formatting.Indented
                , new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
                    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
                }));
}


public T Get<T>(string key) where T :class
{
    var db = this.redisConnections.GetDatabase();
    var redisObject = db.StringGet(key);
    if (redisObject.HasValue)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(redisObject
                , new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
                    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
                });
    }
    else
    {
        return (T)null;
    }
}
```